# Sort String[] array based on number present in the String

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array that looks like:

```
array[] = {1c, 13d, 11d, 10d, 1h, 13h, 5s, 2s, 12d}
```

I want to sort the array based on the number present in the array So the end result would be:

```
{1c, 1h, 2s, 5s, 10d, 11d, 12d, 13d, 13h}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Sure there's a way; what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have not been able to think of a correct logic for this.

Comment: Implement your own Comprator<String> and sort it like you always do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is by implementing the [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface. When you decide how you plan to compare the strings, you can use the utility methods in [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class. Here is a complete working example.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;


public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] myArray = {"1c", "13d", "11d", "10d", "1h", "13h", "5s", "2s", "12d"};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));

        Arrays.sort(myArray, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String one, String two) {

                int oneNum = Integer.parseInt(one.substring(0, one.length() - 1));
                int twoNum = Integer.parseInt(two.substring(0, two.length() - 1));

                char oneChar = one.charAt(one.length() - 1);
                char twoChar = two.charAt(two.length() - 1);

                if (oneNum < twoNum) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (oneNum == twoNum) {
                    if (oneChar < twoChar) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (oneChar == twoChar){
                        return 0;
                    } else {
                        return 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    );

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));   

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had figured out a solution but this code is far  better. :-)

Comment: I assumed the format of the string to have an integer followed by a single char at the end. If that is not the case, you can use a regular expression like one.split("\\D+") to split it properly.

Comment: Yes that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Think about how you'd do this with just paper and pencil (no computer). Chances are you would:

- Go through each element of the array, and convert it to just an integer (i.e. remove the non-numerical characters)
- Sort the resulting integer-only array or list. Hint: `Collections.sort()` is your friend :)